# Your application is missing a Procfile - error while deploying django website on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my very basic django website to heroku and getting error all the time. I have a Procfile.txt and requirements.txt file in the root directory but it keeps on giving the procfile missing error all the time.

My procfile is :

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application --log-file -
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

My requirements.txt is :

```
Django==1.9.8
gunicorn
```

In the build log :

```
-----> Python app detected

 !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.

 !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

-----> Uninstalling stale dependencies

       Uninstalling virtualenv-15.0.2:

         Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-15.0.2

     $ pip install -r requirements.txt

       Collecting gunicorn (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

         Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)

       Installing collected packages: gunicorn

       Successfully installed gunicorn-19.6.0

-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types -> (none)

-----> Compressing...

       Done: 41.3M

-----> Launching...

       Released v7

       https://jpthoyo.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

If this information is not sufficient to find the solution then do tell me .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file should be called just Procfile, not Procfile.txt.

Comment: Yes its named as Procfile and its a txt file

Answer (score 0):

Name the Procfile as "Procfile" without any extension and also make sure it is always in your application root folder. Therefore "Procfile.txt" is invalid since it has an extension "txt".